# How can I convert an swf file to its fla?

Tags: flash

I would like to know if I can convert an swf file to its fla using any free/online application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an application called SOThink SWF decompiler - give that a shot :)

http://www.sothink.com/

Comment: True, but it's the only software I know of that even comes close to yielding an accurate .fla file. Also, the trial version lets you access the content of the .swf excluding the source code which is pretty nifty.